# How can I customize registration-free COM manifests generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, regfreecom

I'm trying to deploy an .NET application with a custom COM component through ClickOnce. Unfortunately the application does not work with manifests generated by Visual Studio to use the COM component in registration-free mode. After a couple of tries I figured out changes were required in the manifest. I need to add a <comInterfaceExternalProxyStub> element to the manifest that gets generated by setting Isolated=True in the properties of a COM reference.

I can do this change manually and then re-sign the ClickOnce manifests with mage in the correct order and the application works. But I'd like to streamline this process, so that the next guy can deploy the application without going through that.

Ideally, I could simply edit some settings in Visual Studio, or manually change the MSBuild project files to have this change made. If that's not possible, I guess I'll have to write a script that makes the change and include it as a post-build step or something.

Is there a way to automate this modification for future deployments?

Comment: It would be easier to just not need the proxy.  Hard to see why you need it in the first place, out-of-process COM has no role in ClickOnce, in-process marshaling is easily avoided by having .NET marshal the call instead of COM.  Nor does .NET let you create a proxy, where did it come from?

Comment: @Hans: the proxy is generated automatically by Visual Studio in a DLL named Interop.Foo.dll when I add a reference to the COM component in a project. I don't understand why it does so, but the app will complain if I don't register the proxy. Oh, and I think this isn't out-of-process COM (that's when you have a COM EXE, like Excel, right?). FWIW, I managed to fix the problem after reading [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic7)

Comment: That's not a proxy, that's a .NET interop assembly.  Proxies are unmanaged DLLs, generated from code produced by midl.exe from an IDL file.  They help COM serialize the arguments of function calls across an apartment or process boundary.  Does any of this trigger an Aha?

Comment: Okay, the example you linked uses the standard marshaller, it uses a type library to marshal a call.  That's pointing at using a COM server from a worker thread, avoided by letting .NET marshal.  Control.Begin/Invoke or Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke.